# equation inside the chart variables

Tags: excel

Is there an excel guru who can help me out?

I made a scatter chart in excel and some of the numbers in Y axis have a negative value inside the square root. These numbers are shown as #NUM! values in the cells.
The X and Y values of the chart have the range from 1 row to 4307 row. Changing the input values to redraw the chart some numbers become #NUM! because of the negative value inside the square root.

Is it possible to add a formula into the Series X and Y values to exclude those cells with #NUM! values in the range from 1 to 4307 cells?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, this isn't possible.

The best you can do is create a named range, and insert that.

You can find it in the Formulas tab under 'Define Name'.

You could define your independent variables with a formula named (say) RangeX:

```
=FILTER(Sheet3!$F$1:$F$4307,1-ISERROR(Sheet3!$J$1:$J$4307))
```

Then define your dependent variables with a formula named (say) RangeY:

```
=FILTER(Sheet3!$J$1:$J$4307,1-ISERROR(Sheet3!$J$1:$J$4307))
```

Now, instead of typing this formula into the 'Edit Series' dialog box, click directly on the line in the graph. The Formula Bar should now have a formula with a `SERIES` function in there. Simply edit this formula like this:

```
=SERIES(,'[Book1.xlsx]Sheet3'!RangeX,'[Book1.xlsx]Sheet3'!RangeY,1)
```

It's important to include the book and sheet prefixes along with the range.

The `SERIES` function is a special function and is historically pretty inflexible; it doesn't like having complicated expressions put into it. But it will accept named ranges.